# Looking for a Batman Comic where Batman had real wings

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman

This is from long ago! I'm 73 years old now and I remember reading a comic when I was a kid where Batman and Robin were in a world where everybody had wings. Batman's wings were bat wings and everyone else had regular bird type wings.
I think it was some alternate universe and Batman and Robin were somehow transported there. I probably read the comic in the 1950s but it could have been published anytime earlier. Since Batman appeared in many different comic titles I have no idea whether it was Detective comics or Batman comics or what but it must have been a DC comic. That's about all I can dredge up from my memory. Hope someone can remember what comic and what issue had this story.

Comment: Aw man, this one is going to be hard. Quote the wikipedia: "In the late 1950s, Batman stories gradually became more science fiction-oriented, an attempt at mimicking the success of other DC characters that had dabbled in the genre. New characters such as Batwoman, Ace the Bat-Hound, and Bat-Mite were introduced. Batman's adventures often involved odd transformations or bizarre space aliens."

Comment: https://i1.wp.com/www.tor.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/FlyingBatman.jpg?fit=756%2C%209999&crop=0%2C0%2C100%2C1062px

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a possibility here.  Did a google image cover search.  The ten cent price on this one puts it in the appropriate timeframe.

[image]

Can't see if the story is the one you're looking for or not.  Did a little digging.  It isn't another planet, but "The Lost Valley of the Birdmen"!  The people are being put upon by a winged family of criminals who have wings.  A group of the people come and get Batman and give him wings (surgically or with a magic formula or something).  They get this know-how from a turncoat member of the family.

Comment: Based on @Valorum's comment, I was able to find this: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_82 Definitely looks like you've found the correct issue. I don't want to add another answer so feel free to edit in details from the article.

Comment: That's the one!  Thanks a bunch.  Knowing which issue it was allowed me to find a copy on line and enjoy it all over again.

Comment: Glad I could help.  I knew the story but am a few years younger than you so I must have seen it in reprint.